# How to connect Oracle database to an Android application?

Tags: java, android, oracle, odbc, ojdbc

I'm developing an Android application to use in a Tablet only in my company, i need to make some querys against the Oracle database, i readed that the only allowed driver to do that is the OJDBC14, i had downloaded and added to the project:

```
String serverName = "192.168.1.132";
String portNumber = "1521";
String db = "XE";
String userName="user";
String password="pass";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":"+ db;
Connection con;   
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);          
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from ht where smt='"+ var + "'" );
while (rset.next())
{
    System.out.println(rset.getString("thing"));
}
rset.close();
stmt.close();
con.close();
```

but when i'm executing i'm getting this:

```
I/dalvikvm(3699): Failed resolving Loracle/jdbc/xa/OracleXAResource; interface 376 'Ljavax/transaction/xa/XAResource;'
```

Some help please?

Answer (score 0):

It is bad policy to make a connection to the database on android.
You should think of a REST server.